# ¿Por qué mi transición desasaparece?

Tags: html, jquery, css, transicion, transition

Al momento de revisar mi código con el inspector, aparece que mi transición esta cancelada ¿por qué sucede esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurren dos razones del porque no funciona, la primera opción es que lo estas sobre escribiendo con alguna otra regla css o bien estas usando un navegador que necesita mas reglas para que funcione, prueba a declarar tu transición para diferentes navegadores.

```
.menu-cont {
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s;
        transition: all 0.5s;
    }
```

o bien revisa que no estés sobrescribiendo tus reglas css.